# Render out promise values for entire object of promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have a whole bunch of these functions and I was wondering how I could value them all out them all out to one object. They can all run in parallel. Is there something baked into [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) to facilitate this?

```
report.osx_serial = function(){
  return execAsync("ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber").spread(rmNewLines).then(rmSerial).catch(returnFalse);
}

report.osx_serial().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new function similar to `Promise.map` that works on objects:

```
function promiseMapObject(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var promises = keys.map(function (key) {
        return obj[key];
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        var resultObj = {};

        results.forEach(function (result, i) {
            resultObj[keys[i]] = result;
        });

        return resultObj;
    });
}
```

and

```
promseMapObject({
    serial: report.osx_serial(),
    …
}).done(console.log);
```

If you have [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/) handy, that’s `zipObject`:

```
function promiseMapObject(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var promises = keys.map(function (key) {
        return obj[key];
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        return _.zipObject(keys, results);
    });
}
```

or even:

```
function promiseMapObject(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var promises = keys.map(function (key) {
        return obj[key];
    });

    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(_.partial(_.zipObject, keys));
}
```

Comment: I don't think `.all()` takes an array of promises https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise :/

Comment: @ThomasReggi: The very first sentence of that is *“Given an array … which contains promises”*.

Comment: Hmm the console log from within that then is all functions for me, not promise values.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Which one? The result of `promiseMapObject`?

Comment: I was passing in the wrong thing (the entire object)! Gotcha!

Comment: [`props`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#props---promise) looks like it does exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: So it does. I completely missed that you were using bluebird. Use that! (This is more or less its implementation based on ES6 standard promises.)